Is it a must that my user model inherits from dm.Model before i can use UserMixin to handle login in python-flask?
I understand that this is the traditional way that people create user model in python-flask:
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}', '{self.image_file}')"

where by their user model inherits from db.Model then UserMixin and then they load user data like this:
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))

However, I created a custom baseModel from which my user model inherits and everything works fine until I want to use UserMixin to handle the login process wherein I keep getting missing user_loader or request_loader error. Below is my staff model and user_loader function.
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    """Return a staff object for an id"""
    return models.get_specific_staff(int(user_id))

class Staff(BaseModel, Base, UserMixin):
    """A Staff object that defines each Efcc staff features"""
    __tablename__ = 'staffs'
    # staff_no = ''

When i tested the load_user() manually it works perfectly. But when i integrated it into my API, I even render then template again even for the landing page that works on GET request. Please what am i getting wrong?

The error you are experiencing has nothing to do with your custom user models. This error means that you do not have a user_loader function registered with your login_manager. Is there any chance that you have defined login_manager twice somewhere?

Thanks buddy, i solved the issue out, here is my answer below.

I solved this problem by ensuring that i used the load_user wrapper in the same module that I instantiated the login manager.
